# Remove few html tag from the html dom

Tags: java, xml

I have below html table. I want to convert it to xml. I have done my coding as below whereby this will convert to html dom first and later i will convert it to xml. My problem is i just want to remain the ,  , and

tag the rest of the tag should not be captured in the document How can i do that? As i would like to change the html table to xml table. So after that i will able to proceed to use list to insert the data to a class which will then be converted ot xml.

```
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();     
is = new InputSource(new StringReader(tableInString));
document = builder.parse(is);
document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 20%;"/>
        <col style="width: 20%;"/>
        <col style="width: 50%;"/>
        <col style="width: 10%;"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="1">
                <p>Header1</p>
            </th>
            <th colspan="2">
                <span><div>Header2</div></span>
            </th>
            <th colspan="1">
                p><a><strong>Header3</strong></a></p>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <div>Value1</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span><div>Value2</div></span>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1">
                <p><a><strong>Value3</strong></a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do consider using XSLT for such transformations rather than using the DOM API. It's often much simpler.

Comment: Do you have aby reference or link for it as XSLT as I search transform XML to other. I could not find html to xml

Comment: Convert your HTML to XML using a tool such as tagSoup or validator.nu, then transform it as XML->XML. Or some processors have extension functions e.g. Saxon has parse-html().